# Android NDK gl using Java nio bytebuffer for texture image

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I am using Java side direct nio buffer which is  holding pixel data from a bitmap and use it in the NDK side as a gl texture. Basically I am not able to read the Java nio buffer pixels correctly in the c/c++ gl draw call.

It appears that the Java.ByteBuffer that is filled with pixels on Java side is not directly compatible with NDK side gl which requires unsigned bytes ( java byte is apparently 32 bit)

so a single white pixel on Java side :

```
int size = 1;
ByteBuffer vv = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size_t*4);
vv.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
vv.put((byte)255); // R
vv.put((byte)255); // G
vv.put((byte)255); // B
vv.put((byte)255); // A
vv.position(0);
... //code to send the buffer address to JNI/NDK gl side
... //
```

will be drawn on NDK side as a  black pixel;

I realize that the actual unsigned byte value of this buffer maybe be negative - how do I correct for this.
Also - I will need to convert byte[] that is an image data derived from a Bitmap on Java side to be used in the NDK side texture once I solve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do a hex dump of the buffer from your native code to make sure the pixel data is actually getting there.

Answer (score 0):

First "byte" in Java is 8 bit (signed) not 32 bit.
I don't use nio.ByteBufffer (though one can). 
byte[] array works much better and simpler.

in AndroidBitmap.java

```
public class AndroidBitmap {

    public static native void updateBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap bitmap, byte[] data, int w, int h, int bpp);

}
```

in AndroidBitmap.c

```
jboolean Java_jni_AndroidBitmap_updateBitmap(JNIEnv* env, jobject that, jobject bitmap, jbyteArray data, jint w, jint h, jint bpp) {

    jbyte* a = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, data, NULL);
    jsize  bytes = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, data);

    AndroidBitmapInfo info = {0};
    int r = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info);
    if (r != 0) {
        // … "AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", r
        return false;
    }
    int width = info.width;
    int height = info.height;
    if (info.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 && info.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_A_8) {
        // "Bitmap format is not RGBA_8888 or A_8"
        return false;
    }
    int bytesPerPixel = info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 ? 4 : 1;
    void* pixels = null;
    r = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels);
    if (r != 0) {
        // ..."AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", r
        return false;
    }
    if (w == width && h == height && bytesPerPixel == bpp) {
        memcpy(pixels, a, width * height * bytesPerPixel);
    } else if (bytesPerPixel == 4 && bpp == 1) {
        grayscaleToRGBA(pixels, &info, data, w, h);
    } else {
        assertion(bytesPerPixel == 4 && bpp == 1, "only grayscale -> RGBA is supported bytesPerPixel=%d bpp=%d", bytesPerPixel, bpp);
    }
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, data, a, 0);
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on 8 vs 32 bit byte in Java. If I trace the sample I provided - all values are -1. I do need to pass the memory address of the nio buffer only and not the actual pixels. The buffer is updated on the java side on the fly and I need NDK side to have access to it directly. I am using the same mechanics to share data from Java side ( floats, int, etc) very quickly, but not byte image data.

Comment: The performance characteristics for byte[], ByteBuffer, and direct ByteBuffer can be different.  See http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_sharing

Comment: 1. In real life byte[] is never copied by VM. And nio.ByteBuffer.put() on android is very expensive relative to a[i] = v; (can be mitigated by mass operations) 
2. in practical projects I don't even marshal byte[] arrays. I do malloc() on jni side return address as 64 bit java long and have memset, memget, memcpy jni ops to manipulate data exposed to java side. The memory allocated by malloc() guaranteed to stay in place (not moved by GC) and fast accessible. You can also share that memory between processes. 
3. My recent measurements shows java calls about 15 times more expensive than C calls